# Django rest framework queryset passing problem

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am having a problem for some days but never get any solution, I tried different approach but not success. I want to pass multiple queryset in the same view or path.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getProduct(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(_id=pk)
    related = Product.objects.filter(category=product.category).exclude(_id=pk).order_by('?')[:4]
    print(related)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I want to pass related product queryset which is related here in the same view. In the first section I will show product details which is working and in the next section I want to show related but now How can I apply that??

I got some solution which told me to go for serializers and change there. But I don't think so because I tried there but how it is possible. So anyone have any better solution. my related object has the same serializer which is productserializer. but eventually it is related product.

#this is my serializer class

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_user(self, obj):
        user = obj.user
        serializer = VendorSerializer(user, many=False)
        return serializer.data
```

#this is my product model

```
class Product(models.Model):

    brand_choices = [

        ('TVS', 'TVS'),
        ('Hero', 'Hero'),
        ('Yamaha', 'TVS'),
        ('Minister', 'Minister'),
        ('Walton', 'Walton'),
        ('Suzuki', 'Suzuki'),

    ]

    user = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=220, null=True, blank=True, choices=brand_choices)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    numReviews = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    discount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    countInStock = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    brandImage = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    isStorm = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=False)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.price = Decimal(self.old_price * (100 - self.discount) / 100)
        return super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-createdAt']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and this is my updated serializer code

```
class ProductWithRelatedSerializer(ProductSerializer):
    related = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_related(self, obj, pk):
        product = Product.objects.all()
        related = Product.objects.filter(category=
            product.category).exclude(_id=pk).order_by('?')[:4].select_related('Product')[:4]
        ps = ProductSerializer(related, many=True)
        return ps.data
```

this is my view

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getProduct(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(_id=pk)
    # related = Product.objects.filter(category=product.category).exclude(_id=pk).order_by('?')[:4]
    # print(related)
    serializer = ProductWithRelatedSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

updated serializerr

```
class ProductWithRelatedSerializer(ProductSerializer):
    related = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_related(self, obj):
        product = Product.objects.all()
        related = Product.objects.filter(category=
            product.category).exclude(_id=obj.pk).order_by('?')[:4].select_related('Product')[:4]
        ps = ProductSerializer(related, many=True)
        return ps.data
```

#product details page I used react can you please check and help me

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Form, Button, Card, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import products from '../products'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { listProductDetails } from '../actions/productActions'
import { productDetailsReducer } from '../reducers/productReducers'
import {InlineShareButtons} from 'sharethis-reactjs';
import {InlineFollowButtons} from 'sharethis-reactjs';
import { addToCart, removeFromCart } from '../actions/cartActions'
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap'
import { Container} from 'react-floating-action-button'


function ProductScreen({ match, history }) {
    
    const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart)
    const { cartItems } = cart

    const removeFromCartHandler = (id) => {
        dispatch(removeFromCart(id))
    }

    const checkoutHandler = () => {
        history.push('/login?redirect=shipping')
    }

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);

    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const [qty, setQty] = useState(1)

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
    const {loading, error, product, related} = productDetails

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listProductDetails(match.params.id))
    }, [dispatch, match])

    const addToCartHandler = () => {
        history.push(`/cart/${match.params.id}?qty=${qty}`)
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
             
                <Button
                    tooltip="Cart"
                    icon=""
                    rotate={true}
                    onClick={handleShow}
                    className="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl"><i className="fas fa-shopping-cart" style={{fontSize:23}}><sup className='shanto'>{cartItems.length}</sup></i></Button>
            </Container>

            <Link to='/' className='btn btn-light my-3'><strong>Go Back</strong></Link>
            {loading ?
                <Loader />
                : error
                    ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
                :(
                            <Row>
                                <Col md={6}>
                                    
                                    <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
                                </Col>
                                
                               
                            
                                <Col md={3}>
                                    <ListGroup variant="flush">
                                        <ListGroup.Item>
                                            <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                                        </ListGroup.Item>

                                        <ListGroup.Item>
                                            <h3>{related.id}</h3>
                                        </ListGroup.Item>


                                        <ListGroup.Item>
                                            Old Price: <strong className="tk">৳</strong><del> {product.old_price} </del>
                                        </ListGroup.Item>

                                        <ListGroup.Item >
                                            Discount: <b>{product.discount}%</b>
                                        </ListGroup.Item>

                                        <ListGroup.Item>
                                            Price: <strong className="tk">৳</strong> {product.price}
                                        </ListGroup.Item>


                                        <ListGroup.Item style={{color: 'red'}}>
                                            <p><b>{product.short_description}</b></p> 
                                        </ListGroup.Item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement an `ProductWithRelatedSerializer` that makes use of the `ProductSerializer` to serialize products. We thus subclass from the `ProductSerializer`:

```
class ProductWithRelatedSerializer(ProductSerializer):
    related = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_related(self, obj):
        related = Product.objects.filter(
            category_id=obj.category_id
        ).exclude(_id=obj.pk).order_by('?').select_related('user')[:4]
        ps = ProductSerializer(related, many=True)
        return ps.data
```

The [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) is not necessary, but will boost the `get_user` method of the `ProductSerializer` for the related products.

This will thus return a response that looks like:

```
{
    /* … */
    "user": {
        …
    },
    related: [
         { "user": { … } },
         { "user": { … } },
         { "user": { … } },
         { "user": { … } }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Then How will I view it in the frontend??

Comment: `data.related` is a list of serialized products. It thus adds an extra field `related` to the "outer" product, and you can enumerate over the list to render the related products, just like you render the selected product.

Comment: I mean what will be my view file and in this serializer it is saying product and pk undefined so I took a query product = Product.objects.all() and then call the product object and for pk I pass it as a parameter but it is saying one positional argument is missing

Comment: @SohanurRahmanShanto16209570: you replace `serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)` in your view with `serializer = ProductWithRelatedSerializer(product, many=False)`

Comment: brother thank you so much for your effort. But it is giving me error like product not found and positional argument pk is missing

Comment: @SohanurRahmanShanto16209570: can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69161083/edit) the question with the full traceback, and the `Product` model.

Comment: yes man wait I will edit and update the code

Comment: brother I have updated my code and post, can you please check and let me know where I did wrong?

Comment: @SohanurRahmanShanto16209570: normally it should be fixed now, but the so `get_related()` should only use `self` and `obj`. I made some mistakes that resulted in `NameError`s, can you try with *exactly* the `get_related` method as described in the serializer? So `.select_related('user')`, not `.select_related('Product')`, etc.

Comment: I tried the same  approach but for pk?? if it won't use any argument (self, obj, pk) so I pass like this?

Comment: @SohanurRahmanShanto16209570: no, it should use `obj.pk` since we want to exclude the record with as primary key the primary key of the object.

Comment: @SohanurRahmanShanto16209570: each model object has an attribute `.pk` that is the value for the primary key field, so in this case `obj._id` and `obj.pk` are equivalent.

Comment: it is saying 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'category'.. related = Product.objects.filter(category=
            product.category).exclude(_id=obj.pk).order_by('?')[:4].select_related('Product')[:4]

Comment: can you check my updated serializer please

Comment: @SohanurRahmanShanto16209570: you are not copying it correctly. It should be `.filter(category_id=obj.category_id)`, so `obj.category_id`, not `product.category`. I have updated the answer, can you please test the `get_related` with the *latest* version of `get_related`?

Comment: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'Product'. Choices are: user, category

Comment: Hey man It worked like a charm. Thank you so much brother. now In the frontend How I should call it?

Comment: @SohanurRahmanShanto16209570: if you make an ajax request, you can get the related products with `.data.related` which is a list of (at most four) related products. If you thus work with a tool like angular, react or vue.js, you can that render the source, otherwise you will need to implement some JavaScript to update the HTML, just like you did when retrieving a single item.

Comment: @Willeman I have updated my code for frontend, can you please check and let me know

Comment: @SohanurRahmanShanto16209570: I think you better ask a new question how to deal with the response of the API view with react. I'm not an expert in react and likely other people can help if you share some sample output data of the API.